# Is it ok to remove and tighten lug nuts with a 3/8" ratchet?

Tags: wheel-lugs

Is this ok or does one really need the 1/2 inch, if so why?

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific about your question. Are you worried that your sockets won't stand up to the torque? Do you have enough leverage with a 1/2 but not enough with a 3/8 due to a lever arm?

Comment: tighten with a torque wrench : see this question (which is also yours)... : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/54225/10976

Comment: @SolarMike I know that is the best practice but I just want to know what I can get away with.

Comment: Then don't tighten with a ratchet - use a T or breaker bar or when there is a specified torque a torque wrench... On a ratchet it's one tooth that takes all the force and they can break...

Comment: @BobCross Well I dont see many people doing it with a small ratchet and I was also advised by a sales advisor to get the 1/2 inch but I've also heard some people say its fine.  Maybe u could explain pros and cons.

Comment: @SolarMike will it only break if you apply to much force so provided you don't over tighten you should be ok?

Comment: @SolarMike let me put it another way as the question wasn't like the previous question.  Can you use a 3/8" torque wrench to tighten lug nuts or do you need the 1/2" torque wrench?  Basically I'm buying tools but don't want to overdo it if  recommended and not really necessary for now.

Comment: A torque wrench and a ratchet are two different things... A 3/8" torque wrench is good for its maximum rating but, personally once I am at 90% of the max I use a larger one anyway. Buy one that covers the range you need... I have two 3/8" torque wrenches as one is for the fixings on my son's carbon-fibre downhill bike and the other goes higher which does most of the fixings I need to work with. Larger one is from Snap-On...

Comment: Depends on how strong you are if it is safe, no good way to know how tight you have gotten them with a short 3/8 ratchet. Best to use a torque wrench....https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/54225/do-i-need-to-use-a-torque-wrench-for-wheel-lug-nuts-and-brake-caliper-bolt?noredirect=1&lq=1